# Google Cloud Firestore error: order by clause cannot contain duplicate fields

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Seeking guidance on the following error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 order by clause cannot contain duplicate fields end_date

I am trying to create an endpoint that searches for documents that have an end date between two dates **and** allows pagination (i.e starting from a particular document).

From the error it seems we cannot use the same field twice (i.e to search between two dates in my case) when also starting from a particular document. Although you can search between two dates without issue when not needing to paginate.

The below code reliably reproduces the error:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from google.cloud import firestore

one_week_ago = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - relativedelta(weeks=1)
one_weeks_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + relativedelta(weeks=1)

collection_name = '...'
starting_doc_id = 'FnAFSazMlXwYWfnEzS1x'  # used to support pagination

client = firestore.Client()
collection_ref = client.collection(collection_name)

start_at_snapshot = collection_ref.document(starting_doc_id).get()
collection_ref = collection_ref.start_at(start_at_snapshot)

collection_ref = collection_ref.where('end_date', '>=', one_week_ago)].where('end_date', '<=', one_weeks_time)

for item in collection_ref.stream():
    print(item.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work, I had to set `order_by` by including `.order_by('end_date')`.

The documentation was not clear about this, so I hope this helps someone in the future.

Final working code is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from google.cloud import firestore

one_week_ago = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - relativedelta(weeks=1)
one_weeks_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + relativedelta(weeks=1)

collection_name = '...'
starting_doc_id = 'FnAFSazMlXwYWfnEzS1x'  # used to support pagination

client = firestore.Client()
collection_ref = client.collection(collection_name)

start_at_snapshot = collection_ref.document(starting_doc_id).get()
collection_ref = collection_ref.start_at(start_at_snapshot)

# note only this line changed
collection_ref = collection_ref.order_by('end_date').where('end_date', '>=', one_week_ago)].where('end_date', '<=', one_weeks_time)

for item in collection_ref.stream():
    print(item.id)
```